# Different layouts on firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm developing a site where the header has cart button and search bar.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw234obf/4/)

My question is in chrome and firefox you will see different spaces between cart button and search input. Chrome version should be the right layout. Any suggestions? Help is appreciated.

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}
img[alt="cart-icon"] {
  width: 20px;
}
img[alt="telephone-icon"] {
  /*width: 18px;*/
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 21px;
}
.tel-no {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -7px;
  margin-right: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: avenirreg;
}
.tel-no p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline;
}
.cart1 {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.top-cart .truncated {
  display: none;
}
.header-search-form {
  float: right;
}
.right input[type='text'] {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #7B7672;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 125px;
  height: 21px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: -19px;
  color: #ccc !important;
}
.right input[type='text']:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #444;
}
.right button[type='submit'] {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  /* background-size: 19px; */
  background-size: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url('../images/ico-search.png') no-repeat center center;
  left: -11px;
  top: 6px;
}
/* firefox*/

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .header-row-1 button[type='submit'] {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    /* background-size: 19px; */
    background-size: 15px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 25px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url('../images/ico-search.png') no-repeat center center;
    left: 0px;
    top: -25px;
  }
}
.header-row-1 button[type='submit']:hover {
  background-color: #ED1B24 !important;
}
.cart-label {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  /* border-radius: 11px; */
  padding: 2px 4px;
  font-size: 9px;
  position: relative;
  top: -9px;
  left: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <div class="tel-no">
    <img src="http://www.encorediamond.co.uk/skin/frontend/ecd/default/images/common/telephone-icon.fw.png" alt="telephone-icon">
    <p><span>015395 67957</span>

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart1">
    <a href="#header-cart" class="toggle-minicart skip-link skip-cart">
      <!--<img src="" alt="cart-icon">
                    <span class="cart-label">5</span>-->


      <img src="http://www.encorediamond.co.uk/skin/frontend/ecd/default/images/common/cart-icon.fw.png" alt="cart-icon">
      <span class="cart-label">
                        0                    </span>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 top-cart" style="display: none">
    <div class="header-minicart">
      <a href="#header-cart" class="skip-link skip-cart  no-count">
        <!--<span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="label"> ( </span>
    <span class="count"> )</span>-->
      </a>

      <div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content">
        <div id="minicart-error-message" class="minicart-message"></div>
        <div id="minicart-success-message" class="minicart-message"></div>
        <div class="minicart-wrapper">
          <p class="block-subtitle">Recently added item(s) <a class="close skip-link-close" href="#" title="Close">×</a>

          </p>
          <p class="empty">You have no items in your shopping cart.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="search_mini_form" action="http://www.encorediamond.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
    <div class="header-search-form">
      <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" autocomplete="off" id="search" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" type="text">
      <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button"></button>
      <div style="display: none;" id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://www.encorediamond.co.uk/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');
         //]]>
      </script>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- <div class="navbar-toggle collapsed mobile-expand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></div>--></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please include following in your CSS this style will apply only for firefox you can give margin bottom only for firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.cart1 {
margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you should use (Edited)

```
#search_mini_form {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 9px;/*Same as .cart1*/
}
```

instead of

```
.header-search-form {
    float: right;
}
```

And replace `position:relative` with `float:right;` for `.right button[type='submit']`:

```
.right button[type='submit'] {
    float:right;
    border: none;
    /* background-size: 19px; */
    background-size: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url('../images/ico-search.png') no-repeat center center;
    left: -11px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

---

`#search_mini_form` is the element containing your `input`, and it is the sibling element of your `.cart1` element. So, if you want to set your layout using `float`, elements you want to position have to be siblings. That's why I set the `float`property to the parent element of your input that is a sibling of `.cart1`

---

> [Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/s6mbmctw/)

Comment: You can still see the space differences under the telephone number.

Comment: Images URLs are wrong, so I cannot see the true result. But thanks to the dev tools, we can see that telephon-icon is not rendered the same in browsers. Setting a `height` value for `img[alt="telephone-icon"]` solve the space difference under the telephone number : http://jsfiddle.net/bdrstmu2/

Comment: Sorry but no progress. Its still same. Can't you see any image?

Comment: No, there are 404 on both phone and cart icon

Comment: Sorry my bad. Site is only for dev access right now. Anyway I'll upload the images.

Comment: Edited my answer and Fiddle